# Seleccionar RadioButton al inicio de la App

Tags: android, kotlin, radiobutton, radiogroup

Buneas,

Quiero que al iniciar mi aplicación, esté seleccionado un RadioButton que está dentro de un RadioGroup.

El dilema está en que en el ViewModel tengo un "filtro" que es un LiveData, el cual es observado por la actividad. Este LiveData, es creado por la clase SavedStateHandle, para preservar el estado aún si la actividad es matada por falta de recursos, de manera que el RadioButton seleccionado debe ser acorde al valor actual de dicho filtro `_currentFilter`. Por eso necesito marcar el RadioButton en tiempo de ejecución y no lo puedo hacer de antemano desde el Layout.

Esto es lo que he intentado:

```kotlin
private fun setupRadioGroup() {
        setupRadioButtonsTag()
        setupInitialFilterSelected()
        setupRadioGroupListener()
    }

    private fun setupRadioButtonsTag() {
        for (i in 0 until binding.rgTasksFilter.childCount) {
            binding.rgTasksFilter.getChildAt(i).tag = TasksFilter.values()[i]
        }
    }

    private fun setupInitialFilterSelected() {
        val position = viewModel.currentFilter.value?.ordinal ?: 0
        binding.rgTasksFilter.getChildAt(position).isSelected = true
    }

    private fun setupRadioGroupListener() {
        binding.rgTasksFilter.setOnCheckedChangeListener { group, checkedId ->
            for(i in group) {
                if(i.id == checkedId) {
                    val filter = i.tag as TasksFilter
                    viewModel.changeFilter(filter)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

```kotlin
 private val _currentFilter = handle.getLiveData(FILTER_SELECTED, TasksFilter.ALL)
    val currentFilter: LiveData<TasksFilter>
        get() = _currentFilter
```

```kotlin
enum class TasksFilter { ALL, PENDING, COMPLETED }
```

```xml
        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/rgTasksFilter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="@dimen/margin_2x">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rbTaskAllOption"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin"
                android:text="@string/tasks_lblFilterAll" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rbTaskPendingOption"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin"
                android:text="@string/tasks_lblFilterPending" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rbTaskCompletedOption"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tasks_lblFilterCompleted" />
        </RadioGroup>
```

El filtro parece estar seleccionado, pero "gráficamente" no aparece marcado.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La vinculación de vista es una función que te permite escribir más fácilmente código que interactúa con las vistas. Una vez que la vinculación de vista está habilitada en un módulo, genera una clase de vinculación para cada archivo de diseño XML presente en ese módulo. Una instancia de una clase de vinculación contiene referencias directas a todas las vistas que tienen un ID en el diseño correspondiente.

En la mayoría de los casos, la vinculación de vistas reemplaza a findViewById.

¿Cómo funciona?

En el "build.gradle" de tu app:

```
android {
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
}
```

En tu Activity:

```
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    val view = binding.root
    setContentView(view)
   
    // Asignamos el valor que queremos a la vista vinculada
    binding.rbTaskAllOption.text = "All"

}
```

Y lo último que te comentaba es que hay otra forma de acerlo que es agregando la variable al layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       <data>
           <variable name="user" type="com.example.User"/>
       </data>
       <LinearLayout
           android:orientation="vertical"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent">
           <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:text="@{user.firstName}"/>
           <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:text="@{user.lastName}"/>
       </LinearLayout>
    </layout>
```

Espero poderte ayudar con esta explicación. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Has probado con la propiedad checked?

```
        <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rbTaskAllOption"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        **android:checked="true"**
        android:text="@string/tasks_lblFilterAll" />
```

Comment: Conocía esa propiedad, pero no puedo usarla, dado que el valor inicial, dependerá del estado de un filtro que reside en el ViewModel.

Gracias por la ayuda igualmente  ^^.

Comment: Entiendo, pero si utilizas view Binding puedes actualizar la propiedad solo poniendo en el  xml -> @{nombreDeLaPropiedad}

Comment: Buenas, no termino de entender tu respuesta. ¿Podrías explicarlo un poco más?

Gracias!